# Location Notification matching current date to date of object

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I have several objects inside an array, each object has it's own date.

I want to fire a local notification whenever the the current date == object date.

I have some code, i would like someone to tell me if it makes sense and if it should work, i have taken care of the delegates and reloadData method.

Here is the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"LiveIdent";

    LiveViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    LiveMatchObject *item = [tableDataLiveMatch objectAtIndex:(int)([indexPath row]/2)];

    if ([item isKindOfClass:[LiveMatchObject class]]) {

        NSString * dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",item.matchDate];

        NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
        NSDate* myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"'Hoje ás' HH:mm 'horas"];
        NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:myDate];

        //// starts here the notification code

        // create a timer to keep track of the current date

        NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
        NSDateFormatter *daterFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [daterFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

        // if current date = date stored in the object then do this

        if (myDate == now){
        UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        localNotification.fireDate = myDate;
        localNotification.alertBody = @"Início da partida";
        localNotification.alertAction = @"Show me the item";
        localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadData" object:self];

        }


            NSArray *localNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [localNotifications objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell.textLabel setText:localNotification.alertBody];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[localNotification.fireDate description]];

   return cell;
}
```

Should this work or this is a total disaster?

P.S - i cannot test, because i reads from live events which actually will occur tomorrow, so i'll have to wait, to see it for myself.

Thank you.

Comment: Comparing object pointers is rarely useful `(mydate == now)` what you always want is whether or not the objects are equivalent `([mydate isEqual:now])` or even, in since your comparing floating point numbers in essence, `(fabs([mydate timeIntervalSince:now]) < 1.)`

Comment: any reason you're scheduling the notification in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`? You schedule notifications when you actually want them to be fired (which I don't believe you're handling either, since there's no automatic action if the app is open).

Comment: you're right this was a total disaster, the app actually crashes

Answer (score 1):

Yes your code is looking good but you can test your local-notification by setting some near time instead of waiting for tomorrow here is the code which I used in my project:

```
  NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
  NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
  [components setDay: 16];
  [components setMonth: 3];
  [components setYear: 2014];
  [components setHour: 10];
  [components setMinute:32];
  [components setSecond: 0];
  [calendar setTimeZone: [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
  NSDate *dateToFire = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
```

Hope this will helps you.